# Usage threads in google tests

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, googletest, stdthread

I want to create some tests to check multi-threading in my application. I use google test framework. My following code is not compiled with error message `error: invalid use of non-static member function`

```
TEST_F( tc, t ) {
  std::thread thread1 ( f1, p1 );
  std::thread thread2 ( f2, p2 );
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();    
}
```

I use GCC 5.2.1 for compiling.

Could you please point me out hot to fix it?

Comment: What is f1, p1, f2, p2?

Comment: @ForEveR, some simple functions and its parameters. In single thread tests I call them like `f1(p1)`

Comment: Your warning message suggests `f1` and `f2` are member functions. That's why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell std::thread that f1 and f2 are methods of your test fixture using `std::bind`:

```
TEST_F( tc, t ) {
    std::thread thread1(std::bind(&tc::f1, this, p1));
    std::thread thread2(std::bind(&tc::f2, this, p2));
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();    
}
```

Comment: Did you assume that f1 and f2 are member functions of tc?

Comment: I didn't just assume it, it's in the error message of the question: "error: invalid use of non-static member function"