# How can I use member functions of google unit test case in thread defined in the unit test?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, scope, googletest

I have a google unit test where I've defined a few functions in it. It looks like the following

```
class MyUnitTest {
protected:
    void SetUp() override;
    void TearDown() override;
    void MyFunction();
};
```

And I have a test case such as the following:

```
TEST_F(MyUnitTest, MyCustomTest)
{
   std::thread t1(MainThreadFunction);
   t1.join();
}

void MainThreadFunction()
{
   MyFunction(); // <--- I cannot call this, as it is out of scope.
}
```

My question is, without making MyFunction a static function, there a way to call MyFunction within MainThreadFunction()? I tried std::bind as suggested here, but it didn't work for me:

[Usage threads in google tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807879/usage-threads-in-google-tests)

Comment: Can you show the attempt you made with `std::bind`?

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this: std::thread thread1(MainThreadFunction, std::bind(&MyUnitTest::MyFunction, this));. I also tried making the function public and not protected but the compiler still complains.

Comment: Please edit the actual question to have this information instead of leaving it as a comment. Also try to be more specific. Instead of "something like this", the actual code you tried, and instead of "the compiler still complains" the actual text of the error message it outputs.

Comment: This does nothing with threads. You want first to learn how to call class member functions from free functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to use a lambda instead of `MainThreadFunction`:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/oszs4Ed6o)

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyUnitTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    void SetUp() override {}
    void TearDown() override {}
    void MyFunction() { std::cout << "\n***** MyFunction *****\n\n"; }
};

TEST_F(MyUnitTest, MyCustomTest) {
   std::thread t1([this](){ this->MyFunction(); });
   t1.join();
}

int main() {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto i{ RUN_ALL_TESTS() };
}
```

In case you need to use `MainThreadFunction`, have it receive a pointer to a member function. Notice, in this case, I had to make `MyFunction` public:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/78hW7qroh)

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyUnitTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    void SetUp() override {}
    void TearDown() override {}
public:
    void MyFunction() { std::cout << "\n***** MyFunction *****\n\n"; }
};

void MainThreadFunction(MyUnitTest* ut, void (MyUnitTest::*MyFunctionPtr)()) {
    (ut->*MyFunctionPtr)();
}

TEST_F(MyUnitTest, MyCustomTest) {
   std::thread t1(MainThreadFunction, this, &MyUnitTest::MyFunction);
   t1.join();
}

int main() {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto i{ RUN_ALL_TESTS() };
}
```